# Get google autocomplete api value on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, optionsAuto);

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){
  //get the autocomplete input value here
  //I want to use autocomplete.getPlace() here

});
```

I am able to do this with 'place_changed' listener as passing the autocomplete object, but I can't get the value selected when I refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using javascript `DOMContentLoaded`

```
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   //get the autocomplete input value here
   //I want to use autocomplete.getPlace() here
});
```